# how do we animate folding of a surface in famo.us?

Tags: javascript, animation, famo.us

I have a surface. I need to animate it to fold (origin) making two halves of surface to one.

```
originMod = new Modifier({
        origin: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

originMod.setTransform(Transform.rotateY(-2), {
    duration: 500,
    curve: 'easeOut'
});
```

this turns the whole surface. i just want the right half of the surface to turn and lay back left half of the surface

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are building something like a book flip animation. I saw your other Question as well. You cannot possibly fold a single surface from its middle. You can create a `View` with two surfaces and add functions in the `View` to flip only the right surface as you are doing now.

But you should first Take a look at using the concept of `Views` and constructors. A good start will be the `SlideShow` tutorial they already have in place.

http://famo.us/university/lessons/#/famous-101/slideshow/1

In your case you probably will have to pass your ajax `URL` to a slide view and process it in Constructor to load data on demand. The SlideShow view will correspond to a book View and a `SlideView` will correspond to a open page with `left` and `right` as two surfaces in the `View`. You need references to left and right surfaces' `modifiers`, which you can use to carryout the animations.